# How to scale segments of a column in an R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, scale

I have a data frame with a numeric value and a category. I need to scale the numeric value, but only with respect to those observations of its own category (hopefully without splitting up the dataframe into pieces and then using rbind to stitch it back up).

Here is the example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 22, 24, 25, 27, 12, 13, 12, 15, 17),
                 y = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"))
```

This function would give me a scale of the whole column, but I want the scales to be in relation only to the same category (ie A, B, and C).

```
df$z <- scale(df$x)
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the same function (`scale`) by group.

In base R

```
df$z <- with(df, ave(x, y, FUN = scale))
df

#    x y        z
#1   1 A -1.26491
#2   2 A -0.63246
#3   3 A  0.00000
#4   4 A  0.63246
#5   5 A  1.26491
#6  20 B -1.33242
#7  22 B -0.59219
#8  24 B  0.14805
#9  25 B  0.51816
#10 27 B  1.25840
#11 12 C -0.83028
#12 13 C -0.36901
#13 12 C -0.83028
#14 15 C  0.55352
#15 17 C  1.47605
```

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(y) %>%  mutate(z =  scale(x))
```

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, z:= scale(x), y]
```